# Cocos2d Particle with Multiple or Random Texture

Tags: random, cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I want to do what the title says.

I have a snow particles setup. Works fine.
But I'd like to have multiple textures for it PER EMITTER.

Is this possible or do I just create multiple emitters?

Comment: STACKOVERFLOW STILL ROCKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple emitters. Cocos2d's particle system only supports a single texture per emitter.

In fact if I remember correctly a particle system emitter always uses a single texture in general, and effects using multiple textures always use multiple emitters. Clever emitters can use a texture atlas though and set each particle's texture frame, but again that's not supported by cocos2d.

Comment: Hey Steffen your site is awesome learn a lot from it, and thanks for answering. You rock so you can edit my post no problem. :)

Comment: This is kind of in the same realm, but can you change the texture of a system and have any already-existing particles keep their old texture?

Comment: nope, a system and its particles use one texture. Change it and it changes for all particles.